Django forms, blank line
In my Django form I have a blank line (_____) when I look at my choices, how to fix this?
Trying to remove this line
Here is the code
special_occasion = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=[('None', 'None'), ('anniversary', 'Anniversary'), ('date', 'Date'), ('business', 'Business')])


This surely a snippet from your model, not the actual form? Can you post what you have for the form? Are you using ModelForm?

No I'm using the models.Model, is this wrong?
class Booking(models.Model):
special_occasion = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=[('None', 'None'), ('anniversary', 'Anniversary'), ('date', 'Date'), ('business', 'Business')])
meal_day = models.DateField()
number_of_guests = models.PositiveIntegerField(
null=True,
validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(6)]
)
customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
is_booked = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # Indicates whether the time slot is booked or not

Consider explicitly specifying this field in form:
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    special_occasion = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('None', 'None'), ('anniversary', 'Anniversary'), ('date', 'Date'), ('business', 'Business')])

